# how to add a applicationDocumentsDirectory for a seperate bundle

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, core-data

We usually follow the below approach for application documents directory as part of core data handler, will the same approach work if the core data is placed in a separate bundle.Its Crashing for me .Can any one help me out

```
- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {

     return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,    NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];

 }
```

Comment: Are you trying to share data between two apps?

Comment: i am try to share the data of a static library with application

Comment: What error message(s) appear when the crash occurs? There's almost always some useful clue there.